# Does the destructor of an object free the memory pointed by the pointer used to create object?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

```
Object obj = *obj_ptr;
```

Does the destructor of obj, e.g. if obj goes out of scope, free the memory allocated by obj_ptr?

Comment: That depends on what the constructor and destructor of `Object` do. In other words, show more code.

Comment: no. it would be true if  `Object *obj = obj_ptr` else, its just a copy of `*obj_ptr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: no, because `obj` is a copy of `*obj_ptr`, not a reference.

But this depends on what the assignment does.

Comment: s/assignment/construction/

Answer (score 0):

Technically it *can*, but that would be extremely bizarre. In almost all cases: no.

The memory where your object lives is allocated with `new`, freed by `delete`. An object doesn't know how it's been allocated. It could be on the stack, it could be via `new`, in an array, placement new, a global variable...